# Eclipse Building workspace fails after importing AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, eclipse, build, android-annotations

Im having a very annoying problem.

I was just following this configuration guide from AndroidAnnotations page https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Project-Configuration

And right after importing the library the Eclipse prompts this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/8p38.png/

"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyCup'.
sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy"

I have done nothing, just created an Android Project and followed the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check for API level(18). Clean up and re build the project

Answer (score 0):

Fix the project name in the AndroidManifest.xml file to ".YourActivity_"